# How to solve the `Autoload error`?

Tags: magento2

I am new in `Magento 2` and today i installed it in my system `window 7`,
and i am using `xampp server`.
my problem is that when i go through this link `http://localhost/magento/` then during this an error generating such as:

**Autoload error**

`Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under application root directory.`

and then after i run this command link `composer install` in command prompt then lots of error i am getting in command prompt like this showing you an image see that please and guide me:
[image]

can anybody help me please i am new here,
step by step guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 depends on a number of PHP extensions that you don't have installed.

Since you're using XAMP you'll need to edit your `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` file and enable each extension as it says in the error message.

To enable the missing extensions:

1. Make a backup copy of your `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` file in case something breaks
2. Open up the original `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` in notepad or any text editor
3. Remove the `;` from the start of the line, of each extension you want to enable ex. `;extension=php_intl.dll` `;extension=php_soap.dll` `;extension=php_xsl.dll`
4. Make sure to save your changes to the file
5. Restart XAMP
6. Try to run `composer install` again